# Can we host two APIs (APNs providers) on single machine who send notification to two different apps?

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I am very new to iOS app development and APNs. I have developed two apps which are configured to receive push notification.

In my test environment, I am hosting two APIs apiAppX and apiAppY written using Javapns library on same machine. apiAppX and apiAppY generate push notifications(alerts) for appX and appY respectively. I am using different p12 file for different app.

The problem is, if I generate APNs certificate for appX first then it receives notification but appY doesnt. If I generate APNs certificate for appY first then it receives notification but appX doesnt.

I think this issue is being caused because I am hosting two providers on one machine. I came to conclusion after reading [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html). Especially, after reading following paragraph:

> Note that provider connection is valid for delivery to only one specific app, identified by the topic (bundle ID) specified in the certificate. APNs also maintains a certificate revocation list; if a provider’s certificate is on this list, APNs may revoke provider trust (that is, refuse the connection).

Am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: You can host both of them on the same machine, but each need to work with its app APNS certificate. Is it doable from your side?

Comment: I have generated two different APNs certificates(.p12) and each API is using the correct .p12 file in Java code to create push notification.

Comment: And each of them is using it's own password I assume?

Comment: for dev i am not using any passwords.